# How to ignore a custom attribute when rendering flask render_template?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have some HTML template, for example:

```html
<span data-test-id="fullName">{{ user.full_name }}</span>
```

↓ in dev/qa environment

```html
<span data-test-id="fullName">Homer Simpson</span>
```

I want to ignore custom attribute `data-test-id` in **production** environment.

```html
<span data-test-id="fullName">{{ user.full_name }}</span>
```

↓ in dev/qa environment

```html
<span>Homer Simpson</span>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `FLASK_ENV` value as a switch and pass it into your `render_template` call as a `kwarg`. You'll want to look into [Jinja2](https://jinja2docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for more powerful functionality.

Flask App

```
import os
...

@app.route('/')
def your_route():
    ...
    environment = os.environ.get("FLASK_ENV", 'dev')
    return render_template('your.html', environment=environment)
```

HTML

```
<span {% if environment != 'production'%} data-test-id="fullName" {% endif %}>{{ user.full_name }}</span>
```